# Symfony 3 DateTimeType Incorrect records

Tags: datetime, symfony, symfony-forms

Form Builder:

```
->add('createdAt', DateTimeType::class, array(
    'label' => 'admin.accountEdit.formCreatedAt',
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
    'html5' => false,
    'widget' => 'single_text'
))
```

I enter the record : 2017-01-01 23:00

But it looks as follows in the database : 2017-01-01 21:00

'Format' parameter is not a problem when the default : 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ'

Comment: It looks like a timezone issue. What is the type of your SQL date field? The format you show from the database seems to have missing data IMO, like seconds and timezone.

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the timezone settings.

```
'model_timezone' => 'Europe/Istanbul',
'view_timezone' => 'Europa/Istanbul',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i'
```

It follows the PHP format:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php